# Output trained parameters of Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

If I am training on a GRU model, is there a way I can output the learnt parameters so that when I train next time with more data, I can initialize with those learnt parameters as a starting point?

Comment: Instead of outputting them, look at saving and loading from a checkpoint: https://keras.io/callbacks/

Comment: @EvanWeissburg  I can only change the code but no control on the environment, therefore I want to get the models and feed the parameters with codes (even subset of parameters is helpful, since it can reduce the time of training)

Answer (score 3):

1. **In case of saving the whole model:**

   ```
   weights = model.get_weights() # Getting params
   model.set_weights(weights) # Setting params
   ```
2. **In case of saving single layer:** You need to find the index of a layer you want to save (let's say that it is `i`), then:

   ```
   weights = model.layers[i].get_weights() # Getting params
   model.layers[i].set_weights(weights) # Setting params
   ```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: For retrieving a layer based on either its **name** (unique) or index you can use `model.get_layer(name=None, index=None)` :-)